# Basic template - new drupal project

Tags: 7

I would like to hear how other Drupal developers / companies are dealing with the following issues:

1. Suppose that as a company you often have to make small Drupal websites with minor changes everytime.
   Example: change theme, customize content types , add banner, ... . Do you use a "standard project" with standard modules , configuration, ..? And if so, how do you do this?
2. There are often security updates in Drupal. Suppose you have 20 drupal websites online and they all need the update. How can you automate this? Or how are you guys handling this?
3. If you have a staging and a production environment. How can you easily synchronize between those two? (dabatase-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) can do all of this:

> Suppose that as a company you often have to make small Drupal websites
>   with minor changes everytime. Example: change theme, customize content
>   types , add banner, ... . Do you use a "standard project" with
>   standard modules , configuration, ..? And if so, how do you do this?

Look at [Drush Makefiles](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_make) (Drush itself now includes makefile support) or [Provision](https://www.drupal.org/project/provision) as tools to easily spin-up very similar Drupal sites.

> There are often security updates in Drupal. Suppose you have 20 drupal
>   websites online and they all need the update. How can you automate
>   this? Or how are you guys handling this?

Again Drush and specifically using `Drush Aliases` and scripting a maintenance task such as `drush @alias up --security-only` using Bash and Cron come to mind.

> If you have a staging and a production environment. How can you easily
>   synchronize between those two? (dabatase-wise)

Drush has a command `sql-sync` which syncs databases. `Drush aliases` can have `Groupings` and so typically for a site you will multiple aliases, 1 per deployment of the website. There is a [Drupal documentation page discussing syncing deployments via Drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/670460). issue something like:

`drush sql-sync demosite.drupal6.local @peer`

to sync 2 locations of a website (such as Dev and Production).

TLDR: Drush! Drush! Drush! :D